# IIS Rewrite Stopped Working for specific URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, ohif

We are trying to integrate OHIF with Orthanc Server. and We are using MVC application to integrate.

When have installed IIS, Orthanc Server on a EC2 machine.

We have configured IIS rewrite, where we will rewrite of the response of the orthanc server.

This was working fine until few weeks back, Now all of sudden the rewrite is not working for few URL. No code changes done.

Please help us on this.

https://book.orthanc-server.com/faq/iis.html

```
  <rules>
    <clear />
    <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^orthancserver/(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="http://127.0.0.1:8042/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
```

All URL Redirect working. And already installed Rewrite Module and I have enabled the proxy too.

Comment: You can help yourself by enabling FRT and analyzing, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: Did you get any error messages? It’s difficult to reproduce your problem just based on these error messages.

Comment: The request fails for only POST request. We are getting 404 for POST. But all GET methods are working fine. Please help on this

Comment: If so, you can follow lex's suggestion and use failed request to get detailed error message.

Comment: Hi @samwu, Captured the IIS Failed Request Log, It seems the IIS Rewrite is working. but after the IIS rewrite it again requesting to original URL which I have used

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/STdOK.png

Comment: Please find the screen shot above.  It again reroutes to web application URL and returns 404 error. please advice.

Comment: Do you have information about 404 errors in your frt?

Comment: Hi @samwu, From MVC web application we are calling IIS rewrite URL. I think as per tracing the IIS rewrite redirect the request to localhost but after that again it tries to call URL of the application which is not there, So it's throws 404 error.